# After closing the WinJS appbar , content becomes unscrollable

Tags: javascript, winjs

I'm creating my first app here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image]

After I click on the appbar and then I close it , I can't scroll down to see the rest of the text.

Here's how the code for the appbar looks:

```
<div id="appBar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="{placement: 'top', layout: 'commands'}">
     command1
     command2
     command3
     command4
</div>
<div id="main_content">
</div>
```

I use fragments to navigate using the appbar and I display the fragments in the main_content so idk why it has problems.

Comment: Can you create an online demo that repros the issue. I work in the vicinity of the WinJS team and would be happy to share it with them if we cannot determine the cause here.

Comment: http://andreixd23.ddns.net/

Comment: Content appears unscrollable for me even before opening the appBar.

Comment: hmm I can scroll right when I open the page , should I post the whole code?

Comment: Chrome and Internet Explorer are behaving differently immediately on load. Chrome will scroll but IE will not. If I maximize Chrome, and then restore it, Chrome will no longer scroll either.

Comment: Please don't make any changes to this document while we're debugging the issue. If you need to, please make a copy of this in some place that it can remain untouched.

Comment: Oh okay, I'm not going to touch it

Comment: It appears Chrome is not properly respecting `html { overflow: hidden }` being set in `ui-dark.css` on line 683.  It's allowing me to scroll until I maximize/restore the browser, at which time it stop scrolling.

Comment: And is there a way I can work my way around this without cutting the height of my description div?

Comment: My bet is that the UI isn't supposed to scroll vertically, and that Chrome is not respecting that until it is resized. Please reduce this too as little code as is possible and [submit an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/winjs/winjs).

Comment: Ok I will reduce it to only 1 page, tomorrow,  to see if it behaves the same and if it does I will submit it on GitHub, thanks for your help